# How to prevent EF from creating a foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two tables Tenant and Language. A Tenant has one property for a default language and a second property for a list of possible alternate languages (inclusive of the default language). The Language table is just a reference table of a list of all possible language options. It does not need to contain any information about any other table. After configuring EF as best as I know how, it creates a TenantId foreign key in the Language table.

What about my configuration is causing this and how can I stop it?

**Tenant Configuration**:

```
public class TenantConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Tenant>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tenant> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.HasOne(tenant => tenant.RootFolder).WithMany().OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade); //unsure
        builder.HasMany(tenant => tenant.Languages).WithOne().OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        builder.Property<Guid>("DefaultLanguageId");
        builder.HasOne(tenant => tenant.DefaultLanguage).WithMany().OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

**Language Configuration**:

```
public class LanguageConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Language>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Language> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

**Entity model**:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    
    public virtual DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

**Tenant model**:

```
[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public virtual Folder RootFolder { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual IList<Language> Languages { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

**Language model**:

```
[Table("Language")]
public class Language : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the generated, incorrect [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWS0E.png)

Edit:
I am expecting the schema to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrOEp.png). The Tenant table will hold references to Id's in the Language table. Languages shouldn't know which Tenants reference them.

Comment: And what is your proposal that the database schema should look like? It's not clear to me how database tables should reference each other without a foreign key.

Comment: @Klamsi I added an image with the schema I am expecting

Comment: As *one* column in a database obviously can only store *one* value I doubt you can store here *many* Languages. With 1 to many relations you always have to store on the many side. There is nothing like a "List" column type in SQL.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for reminding me of that. I will need a joining table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you create a property `Languages` as a **list** in the *Tenant* model. Lists in relational databases do not exist. You cannot have a attribute that contains multiple values. EF does the following: It looks at the `IList<Language> Languages` property. Then it goes to the *Language* model and adds a Foreign Key attribute linked to the *Tenant* model.

After looking at your explanation it seems like you want to create a N:M relationship, since you want to link multiple *languages* to a *Tenant*. For this you'll need a [Associative entity (junction table)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). This is because you are trying to establish a N:M (Multiple to Multiple) relationship between two tables.